# How to check for empty for-each in xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

```
Further information:
<ul style="margin:0px; padding:0px 15px;">
  <xsl:for-each select="footer/event_links/links">
    <li style='color:#fff'> <a href="{url}" > <xsl:value-of select="text" disable-output-escaping="yes"/> </a> </li>
    <img moz-do-not-send="true" src="{$tpl_resource_url}images/spacer.gif" width="100" height="10" alt=""/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

I have the above block of xsl code. I want to ensure that it only exists if there are any elements in **footer/event_links/links** That is, if the for-each returns no elements then I do not want to display the text further information.

I tried like below; however, it does not seem to work. The text further information shows up no matter what. How to check for empty for-each?

```
<xsl:if test="footer/event_links/links != ''">
    Further information:
    <ul style="margin:0px; padding:0px 15px;">
      <xsl:for-each select="footer/event_links/links">
        <li style='color:#fff'> <a href="{url}" > <xsl:value-of select="text" disable-output-escaping="yes"/> </a> </li>
        <img moz-do-not-send="true" src="{$tpl_resource_url}images/spacer.gif" width="100" height="10" alt=""/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl>
```

Comment: Use a test after `xsl:for−each`, like `<xsl:if test="current() != ''">`, or do the loop for non empty elements, like `<xsl:for-each select="footer/event/links[.!='']">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've fallen into the "!=" trap. In XPath, the expression `A/B != ''` is true if there is a node selected by A/B whose value is something other than ''. If there is no node selected by A/B, the expression is false. So you want:

```
<xsl:if test="footer/event_links/links">
    Further information:
    <ul style="margin:0px; padding:0px 15px;">
      <xsl:for-each select="footer/event_links/links">
```

There's a special construct in XSLT 3.0 for this, to avoid having to test the same condition twice (which is bad news because it prevents streaming):

```
<xsl:sequence>
  <xsl:on-non-empty>Further information:</xsl:on-non-empty>
  <xsl:conditional-content>
    <ul style="margin:0px; padding:0px 15px;">
      <xsl:for-each select="footer/event_links/links">
        <li style='color:#fff'> 
         <a href="{url}" > 
           <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
         </a> 
       </li>
        <img moz-do-not-send="true" src="{$tpl_resource_url}images/spacer.gif" width="100" height="10" alt=""/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:conditional-content>
</xsl:sequence>
```

Here `xsl:on-non-empty` is evaluated only if it isn't the only thing output by the `xsl:sequence`, and `xsl:conditional-content` discards empty elements (i.e. an empty `<ul/>`) from its result.

**2020 UPDATE**

In the final XSLT 3.0 spec, the `xsl:conditional-content` instruction was renamed `xsl:where-populated`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:if test="footer/event_links/links">
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:if>
```

The empty node set evaluates to false. In other words, selecting nodes is enough to test for their existence, you don't need to do an explicit comparison.

Comment: Hmm I thought it worked.. However it didnt. It needs to look inside the for-each and see if there is any contents. If there is no contents at all, then do not display the text otherwise display the text at header just once..

Comment: You can't "look inside the for-each" (this does not even make sense). The for each only runs when there are nodes that are selectable by `footer/event_links/links` and the `<xsl:if>` tests for just that. Also I'm not sure what you mean by "does not work". That's not an error description.